# Windows Command Line - Multiple PHP Versions

Tags: windows, php, command-line-interface

I am currently running Wampserver with multiple PHP versions (5.3.8, 5.4.3). Wampserver easily allows you to switch back and forth between the php version you want apache to use. However, I'm having trouble dealing with multiple versions from the CLI. I have projects that require the command line, but some are compatible with php5.4, while some are not.

Is there a way to create some type of "alias" in Windows that allows me to specify which version of PHP to use on the command line... I.E: `php54 cache:clear`, `php53 cache:clear`?

Comment: Setting aside the truly horrific nature of what you're doing here for a moment, your question is unclear and possibly overly broad. In the general case, you should be able to refer to the specific version install location and/or binary of PHP you desire to operate on/with that specific version.  Is that not working for some reason?

Comment: Why is this such a horrific nature if I may ask?  Are you referring to different projects using different versions of PHP?  Some of my older client projects have not yet been made compatible with PHP5.4 yet (and their production server is still running php5.3.8), so I must switch to PHP5.3 to perform maintenance on them. 

Just looking for a shortcut to do this instead of typing the full path "c:\wamp\www\bin\php\php5.4.3\php INSERT CMD HERE" every time I need to run a command.

Comment: WAMP, different versions of PHP... PHP in general,  doing any of this with cmd.exe... it's all just pretty horrific, frankly.  Like trying to run a Linux, IIS, MSSQL, Powershell stack.  With different versions of Powershell.  From a bash shell.  I'm getting PTSD just thinking about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to make use of the 'PATH' environmental varibale, and rename the.  PHP binaries to be different (if they're not already).  Add both PHP install directories into the 'PATH' and they'll both be searched when you run an executable from the command line, so you won't have to type out the full path every time.  (Of course, since any directory in there will be searched, it's important you have the different PHP binaries named differently.)

Comment: Thanks.. This is the route I will probably take.  I definitely would like some insight on your 'horrific nature' comment though if possible.  I am worried there is something I am missing here.